# update different item when iterating Hashmap

Tags: java, dictionary, iterator, hashmap

I have a hashmap which I iterate on EntrySet. Is it safe to get a different item from map while iterating and then updating it's value like below?

```
for (Entry<String, EmpData> entry : strEmpDataMap.entrySet()) {
    EmpData data = entry.getValue();
    String manager = data.getManager();
    // getting different item from same map inside loop and updating value
    EmpData managerData = strEmpDataMap.get(manager);
    managerData.setRepCount(managerData.getRepCount() + 1);
}
```

Assuming I have all null checks in place, I think it is safe to get a different item and modify it's value while iterating. Can someone confirm? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is safe. The only changes that you cannot make while iterating over a `Map` are ones that add or remove entries. (Actually you can remove an entry with an `Iterator`'s `remove` method). Getting a value and mutating it is ok.